# Multiple CSS loading re-ordering issue

Tags: java, html, css, spring-mvc, web

I have two project Project-1 and Project-2. Project-1 is main project that contains all application feature and Project-2 is separate project that has Header and footer page so Project-1 render header and footer from Project-2.
Both Project run on same server.

Issue is that both project has xyz.css file and loading from different location.
and css file from Project-2 is loading at last.
How to reorder css loading so that css file from project-1 load at last and from project-2 load at first.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: have you tried delay js function and then load CSS as preferred

Comment: I also faced the same issue, delay js function didn't work for me.